# venting dryer into unused lined chimney flue

Tags: gas, venting

I have vented a gas clothes dryer into an unused terre cotta lined chimney flue in the basement.  The chimney is shared with another lined chimney flue venting the gas hot water heater.  The chimney is 2-1/2 stories high.  My wife worries about this setup and lint buildup in the liner. The dryer dries very well.   Is this an issue?

Answer (score 4):

If you check the dryer installation instructions, you likely will not find any specifications for venting thru the roof. It is generally not recommended. I know my dryer blows a decent amount of lint out the vent. I can't imagine the dryer being able to push the lint out of a 30 foot chimney. I would vent it with rigid duct thru the closest wall.